# What to do when your boss betrays you?

Tags: management, new-job

I suggested to my ex-boss to go work for him again. After some negotiation, we agreed on 2 important conditions.

Starting from my 2nd week, I started to understand that he was going to violate these 2 conditions, knowing that I was not under pressure to leave my previous job anymore.

Should I tell HR?

Comment: Are these conditions written down anywhere?

Comment: No, nowhere at all.

Comment: If they are not in writing, your position is very weak indeed. Was there a reason not to get them in writing? Has he been a reliable boss before (before he became "ex-boss")? Why did you leave him in the first place?

Comment: The project, but I was doing this temporary-permanent task that was not among my objectives of joining this company. I left because I was proposed another job and they were not going to negociate with me. I cameback because I heard the task I am doing were moved to another agency.

Comment: "I heard..." unless you have it in writing on gold plate don't be a believer... and even if it is in writing don't count your chickens...

Comment: Surely the only solution is to **finally learn that words mean nothing - absolutely nothing.**

Comment: How plausible is getting your old job back?

Comment: @bruglesco, my previous manager did everything to keep me, and was very angry when I resigned. He was very kind to me. I don't think he would be willing to give me another chance.

Answer (score 3):

So we start with

> After some negotiation, we agreed on 2 important conditions.
>
> Starting from my 2nd week, I started to understand that he was going
>   to violate these 2 conditions, knowing that I was not under pressure
>   to leave my previous job anymore.

And then follow up from a comment about the conditions being written down:

> No, nowhere at all

At this point it becomes a he said/she said argument between you and your boss.  So there is nothing concrete you can take to HR, and you have already started work and (most likely) signed a contract for your current work conditions.

Thus IMHO there is nothing to gained from going to HR, but you risk being labeled a trouble maker - not something you want early on before you have established yourself in this new company.

So I see you have 2 options:

1. Put up with the actual conditions
2. Leave

There may be a third option of convincing your boss to stand by what he said, but given that he basically lied to your face I doubt it is a realistic option.

Answer (score 2):

So you are one hundred percent sure that there was a verbal agreement, and that your boss intends to be in breach of your verbal agreement. A verbal agreement is a legal contract that he is not allowed to breach - which is what should determine your attitude to things. It's also a legal contract which you can't prove - which is what should determine what legal actions you take.

Since your boss is in breach of a legal agreement, we are all in total agreement that you owe him absolutely zero loyalty, you owe him nothing. So first you start looking for alternative job; if you find one and sign a decent contract, you can tell your boss that you are leaving. Your notice is what is contractually required, which in the USA or elsewhere during your probabition period may be zero. The bigger mess you leave him in, the better.

If you are confident of finding another job, and confident in your job, you can talk to your boss, remind him of his promises, and tell him that you expect these promises to be kept. Don't argue about it, just put him on notice that you strongly disagree with his behaviour.